# Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой при масштабировании

Tags: html, css

В общем, при смещении масштаба страницы контент выезжает за пределы страницы,хотя должен уходить вниз друг под друга.Объясните,пожалуйста, в чем проблема?Буду очень признателен.[ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/artem-shilov/Daru-Link.git)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

У вас на "контейнерах" с элементами стоит `display: flex`
Но не установлено свойство `flex-wrap: wrap`, которое позволяет переносить контент если он не вмещается

Условный ваш код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid dodgerblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 140px;
  border: 2px solid orangered;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При добавлении `flex-wrap: wrap` элементы переносятся

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* добавлено для переноса */
  border: 4px solid dodgerblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 140px;
  border: 2px solid orangered;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* добавлено для отступа */
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD**

Так же можете воспользоваться гридами + медиа-выражениями

Comment: Нужно к каждому флексу прописывать данное свойство? Или есть вариант применить ко всему коду? Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Можно сделать такую конструкцию ```* { flex-wrap: wrap }```, но я думаю это плохое решение. Лучше проставить где нужно